# Keep printing compiler warnings from compiled code using g++ and Makefiles

Tags: c++, makefile, warnings

I have a Makefile that only compiles/recompiles what's necessary. However, even after something is compiled I would like to see their compile warnings.

My scenario is this:
1) I make a file called snake.cpp.
2) I make my project. snake.cpp has 3 warnings and 0 errors.
3) I make another file called cup.cpp
4) I make my project, now I see cup.cpp's warnings but none of snake.cpp's warnings.

But I want to see snake.cpp's warnings, even though the compiling is skipped by make. I don't want to recompile the whole project with -Werror. In fact, I don't want to recompile anything unless I actually edited the relevant files, but I would still like to see the warnings.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Well, either the compiler sees the file and can warn, or it doesn't see it and can't warn... decide what you want!

Comment: You want to see output from stages that are not run. I guess that's only possible with some kind of system with log files: for each step redirect output to a file and during each run echo all log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiling isn't skipped "by mistake", it's skipped because the executable/object is newer than the source.  That's how makefiles work.  And the *only* way to get the warnings without recompiling is by storing them somewhere.  It sounds like your solution is to redirect errors to a log file and print them back out when you `make`.  Perhaps this will work, but I haven't tested it:

```
all: snake cup
    @cat snake.err
    @cat cup.err

snake: snake.cpp
    g++ snake.cpp -o snake 2>snake.err

cup: cup.cpp
    g++ cup.cpp -o cup 2>cup.err

.PHONY: all
```

If they're both part of the same executable you'll want to make objects instead.

Comment: A good solution that will do what I want. I just need to add a dummy target so that .err files are printed even if all targets are compiled. Thanks.